# Email copy of Cognito Form results

Tags: cognito-forms

I am using the my form to conduct and document site inspections for my non-profit's partners. I would like to be able to enter their email address and upon form submission, have them emailed a copy of the form results as well as have the results appear on my "entries" page (where I then download as PDF and place into their file.)

Is this a capability of the system?

As I work for a non-profit, I am using the free version (I only have one form and am the only user/editor of that form).

Answer (score 2):

I'm part of the [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) team.

What you described are definitely current capabilities of Cognito Forms! You can email your partners upon form submission with the help of [notification](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails) and [confirmation](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/13/building-forms/confirmation-emails) emails. These emails can include entry details, receipts, and PDF copies of the entry.

Once a form is submitted, it will automatically appear in your Entries page, where you can export it to an Excel spreadsheet or PDF document.